# Complex filter for SQL Server Merge Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, merge-replication

We have a table in an SQL Server 2012 database that stores tree-like structures. Simplified for the purpose of my question, it has the following format:

```
    Id int identity,
    ParentId int,
    GroupId int
```

Each record of the table represents an object identified by Id. An object may or may not have a parent in the same table, such that *object.ParentId = parentObject.Id*. A root object has *ParentId = NULL*. There are multiple root objects, so the table in fact stores multiple trees.
What’s important is that the tree depth is not fixed, i.e. theoretically there can be any number of ancestor generations for an object.
*GroupId* is a property of a root object; in theory none of the children of a root object has to have *GroupId <> NULL*; it can be assumed that any child has the same *GroupId* value as its root object.

A sample table having two roots (one grandparent and one parent), one non-root parent/child and 4 child roots:

```
    Id       ParentId    GroupId
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1        NULL          200           root grandparent
    2        1             NULL          non-root parent/child
    3        2             NULL          child
    4        2             NULL          child
    5        NULL          300           root parent
    6        5             NULL          child
    7        5             NULL          child
```

The table is not normalised, i.e. there’s no separate {root_object : group} table. However I don’t think normalising the table would have helped to solve the problem.

Now **the problem**. We need to set up *merge replication* from the table above (Master table) to the table of the same format in another DB. We need to replicate only those rows of the Master table that have a certain fixed *GroupId* value, e.g. 200 in the example above. If we ensure that *GroupId* in all descendant objects of a root object has the same value in the table as the root object itself that would be trivial. The table would look like this:

```
    Id       ParentId    GroupId
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    1        NULL          200            root grandparent
    2        1             200            non-root parent/child
    3        2             200            child
    4        2             200            child
    5        NULL          300            root parent
    6        5             300            child
    7        5             300            child
```

And the filter would look like this:

```
    WHERE GroupId = 200
```

However out of performance considerations, we would like to avoid if possible filling *GroupId* for the descendant objects, because as it must be clear from the above, *GroupId* for a descendant object is quite easily deducible via a stored procedure or UDF (just need to go up the tree until *ParentId = NULL*).
The problem is, I don’t know how to achieve this in a merge replication filter: it would only allow *WHERE* conditions and joins. I’ve have not had much luck with joins for merge replication in general, but here we have more complex algorithm, because the number of tree levels can be different for every object.
And merge replication would not allow using UDF…

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using a UDF and that's worked!
I did try that before before, but it failed back then, I don't remember why. Now I think I might not have added the UDF to the subscription DB, only to the publishing DB...